# Issue with CSS display property

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to show a remove button when something like the edit button is clicked and in normal cases I don't want to show it.

In the normal case, the remove button is not showing up, but when we go and place/hover the mouse on the position where that remove button is placed and click it(here we cant see a remove button), all that functionality is happening which will happen when button is clicked.

When i want to show the remove button,

```
<?php if($something){ ?>
<i class="fa fa-times-circle remove"
style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;"  
onclick="function('parameter')"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

When I don't want to show the button,

```
<?php if($someOTHERthing){ ?>
<i class="fa fa-times-circle remove"
style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;display: none"  
onclick="function('parameter')"></i>
<?php } ?>
```

and JavaScript code when edit button is clicked,

```
$('.remove').css('display', 'inline');
```

Comment: You're making a click on the `i` element, I don't see any buttons

Comment: Couldn't really follow what you are trying to say. Can you create a demo?

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to understand the problem, do you have fiddle or similar?

Comment: Yes am clicking on i with an font awesome icon, i want to show and hide that icon , depending upon which case it is, see those two php scripts above.. the problem the icon is hiding but the functionality is working when we hover and click on it

Answer (score 0):

Just assign and remove the click handler using jQuery. It's cleaner than having it in your HTML anyway.

So when the edit button is clicked, you'll have:

```
$('.remove').css('display', 'inline');
$('.remove').on('click', function () { 
  // Your code here
});
```

And when the remove button should hide:

```
$('.remove').css('display', 'none');
$('.remove').off('click');
```